# Differentiate MYSQL Query for entries with similar numbers (17, 170, 171)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on trying to find id's within a database. I need to find the following:

17,
,17 
,17,

Making sure not to find any other id's that start with 17 (i.e. 170, 171, 173, etc). Currently I've set up the following variables to pull into a mysql query:

```
$userid = '' . $row['userid'] . ',%';
$userid2 = '%,' . $row['userid'] . '%';
$userid3 = '' . $row['userid'] . '%';
```

But I'm finding that I'm also pulling in id 170. I think it happens whenever id 170 is put at the end of a string. Any help you can provide I would most appreciate. Here is the query I'm working with:

```
"SELECT formid, draft, activestatus 
 FROM forms
 WHERE notifyusers like '$userid' 
 AND activestatus != '3' OR notifyusers like '$userid2' AND activestatus != '3' 
 OR notifyusers like '$userid3' AND activestatus != '3'";
```

Comment: Could you use MySQL IN, instead of like. Is it only '17,', ',17', ',17,' you need to match?

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with IN, but those are the only format conditions I need to meet. It sounds like IN is really a replacement for OR.

Comment: you've shoehorned a 1->many relation as a CSV list - you'd have an easier time of it if you made that relation a separate table, where each row relates a single form to a single user id.

Comment: If you can modify the database model, you should do so. As I understand it, `notifyusers` can have more than value, so that your database is not even in [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Move the users to a separate table, as suggested by @PaulDixon, and everything you ever have to do with the users will be much easier in future.

Comment: Totally agreed, this was my first stab at php/mysql. We are going to be recreating this website in the future, but need a quick fix for the current one.

Comment: I'm checking 3 times because the id could formatted in these ways: "17," ",17" or ",17,"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function, something like this:

```
SELECT formid, draft, activestatus 
FROM forms
WHERE
  (FIND_IN_SET('17', notifyusers)>0 AND activestatus != '3')
  OR ...
```

or you can use LIKE this way:

```
WHERE
  CONCAT(',', notifyusers, ',') LIKE ('%,17,%')
```

Comment: Won't that still find 170?

Comment: @nate8684 both solution will only find 17 and not 170 or 117, on the LIKE condition I'm searching for ,17, so I have to make sure that notifyusers always begins with , and ends with , (hence the CONCAT)

Comment: can I use a variable in that: (FIND_IN_SET($userid, notifyusers)>0?

Comment: @nate8684 You may need to use it as a string, as per your example that would be `FIND_IN_SET('$userid', notifyusers)`.

Comment: Ok, I have the following variables

$userid = $row['userid'] . ',';
$userid2 = ',' . $row['userid'] . ',';
$userid3 = ',' . $row['userid'];

and am using this query:

$qn = "SELECT formid, draft, activestatus FROM forms WHERE (FIND_IN_SET('$userid', notifyusers)>0 AND activestatus != '3' OR (FIND_IN_SET('$userid2', notifyusers)>0 AND activestatus != '3' OR (FIND_IN_SET('$userid3', notifyusers)>0 AND activestatus != '3'"; 

But it's not working.

Comment: Using any of these approaches, you should not need `$userid2` and `$userid3` at all.

Comment: It's not just '17' that I need to find. This variable changes and pulls  users that are tied to the form. The format is the same, but I need to find different id's

Comment: @nate8684 why are you checking multiple times for `activestatus != '3'`? i think you need just one FIND_IN_SET, and you need just one $userid, the one with 17 ... but you should also be careful about sql injections

Comment: I'm checking 3 times because the id could formatted in these ways: "17," ",17" or ",17,

Comment: @nate8684 if you use FIND_IN_SET, or if you use CONCAT(',', user, ',') LIKE ('%,user,%') you need to check only once

Comment: Got find in set to work, was a stupid issue on my end. Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your notifyusers column contains a 1->many relation as CSV data? Why not exploit the thing relational databases are really good at? You know, relations! Create a separate table to store links between a formid and a userid:

```
CREATE TABLE form_notifyuser
(
   formid INT NOT NULL,
   userid INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(formid, user_id),
   INDEX(user_id)
);
```

Now your query is much easier to express and read!

```
SELECT forms.formid, forms.draft, forms.activestatus 
 FROM forms
 INNER JOIN form_notifyuser USING(formid)
 WHERE form_notifyuser.userid = 17 AND  forms.activestatus != 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `notifyusers` looks like this:

```
,1,2,7,9,70,
```

Note the trailing and leading `,`.
To generate it do something like:

```
$value = "," . implode(",", $ids) . ",";
```

This allows a filter like:

```
WHERE `notifyusers` LIKE '%,7,%'
```

to always work, even if `7` is *at the end*

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd that you would have id values with commas in them.  To me that sounds like the problem  would fix first.  Having said that, a wildcard match using `LIKE('17%')` is never going to be able to differentiate between `17,` and `170` (or even `1700000` for that matter) as it doesn't care what the value in the wildcard position is. You will need to use `REGEXP` to do this sort of specific match if you need to look for multiple different characters besides commas but need to be specific about the accepted values.

Either that or you can just specifically use commas ionstead of `%` and just search for `notifyusers = '17,' OR  notifyusers = ',17,' OR notifyusers = ',17'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$userid =         $row['userid'] . ',%';
$userid2 = '%,' . $row['userid'] . ',%';
$userid3 = '%,' . $row['userid']       ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
"SELECT formid, draft, activestatus 
 FROM forms
 WHERE concat(',',notifyusers,',') like '%,".$row['userid'].",%' 
 AND activestatus != '3'";
```

Comment: This query is not working. It's basically pulling of the logged in users project but nothing else. I'm not even sure what it's doing exactly. Thoughts?

Comment: You certainly have something wrong in the code around this cause it supposed to work.